# Wordpress Default logo is showing in Google Search Console

Tags: wordpress

we are seeing Wordpress Default logo in google Search Console
we don't know what to do with it we checked Favicon on this link https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=your-site-domain.com but it showing the Wordpress defaul logo
no idea what to do now ? Favicon is showing in browser tab as well but it;s not showing on Google Search Console
Appreciate your response
Thanks

We Tried everything with link tag but it didn't work